# Palindrome that skips things that are not letters and doesn't care about upp/lower cases

Tags: java

my goal is to create a code that checks if a word is or isn't a palindrome while skipping everything that isn't a letter and also doesn't take into account upper and lower cases.
 I need to stick to my method, can't use advanced commands even though I'm sure there is a better way of writing this code.
the issue is that variable "a" and "b" never changes and keeps checking the same thing over and over.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String palindrom = "*0Anna'/";

    boolean jeto = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < palindrom.length() / 2; i++) {

        int j = palindrom.length() - 1 - i; // right side
        int a = palindrom.charAt(i); // left side defined by charAt
        int b = palindrom.charAt(palindrom.length() - 1 - i); // right side 
        defined by charAt

        if (palindrom.charAt(i) - 32 == palindrom.charAt(palindrom.length() - 1 - i) || (int) palindrom.charAt(i) + 32 == (int) palindrom.charAt(palindrom.length() - 1 - i) || palindrom.charAt(i) == palindrom.charAt(palindrom.length() - 1 - i)) {
            jeto = true; 

        } else {
            jeto = false;

            while (i < j) {
                if (a < 65 || a > 90 && a < 97 || a > 122) {
                    i++; // checks the left side for "non-letters" => skip
                }

                if (b < 65 || b > 90 && b < 97 || b > 122) {
                    j--; // checks the right side for "non-letters" => skip

                }

            }

        }
    }
    if (jeto) {
        System.out.println("is");
    } else {
        System.out.println("isn't");

    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing all non alphabetic characters before checking for palindrome

```
palindrom = palindrom.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", "");
```

Comment: also convert everything to UPPER prior to checking

Comment: Of course it works, a very simple solution. The only issue is that I am not allowed to use these commands. I should get by with the knowledge that I have (seen in my code).

Comment: @Alexandr U Can you use Character.isAlphabetic() method ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex or `Character.isLetter()` function to eliminate the chars which are not letters.

But if you want to stick with your method and don't want to use advanced commands, define your own isLetter function:

```
public static boolean isLetter(int c){
    return (c>=65 && c<=90) || (c>=97 && c<=122);
}
```

And, check all chars in the string, then apply your algorithm:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String input = "*0Anna'/";
    String palindrom = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        if(isLetter(input.charAt(i)))
            palindrom += input.charAt(i);
    }

    //Rest of the code

}
```

Output:

```
is
```

Also, not related with main issue, but you can change your `if (palindrom.charAt(i) - 32 == palindrom.charAt(palindrom.length() - 1 - i) || (int) palindrom.charAt(i) + 32 == (int) palindrom.charAt(palindrom.length() - 1 - i) || palindrom.charAt(i) == palindrom.charAt(palindrom.length() - 1 - i))` row with `if (a - 32 == b || a + 32 == b || a == b)`. They do same job.